# Proximal Operator / Mapping of $ g \left( x \right) = {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} $ ($ {L}_{1} $ Norm) in the Complex Domain

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, proximal-operators

The $ \operatorname{Prox}_{g \left( \cdot \right)} $ operator is given by:

$$ \operatorname{Prox}_{\lambda g \left( \cdot \right)} \left( x \right) = \arg \min_{u} \left\{ g \left( u \right) + \frac{1}{2 \lambda} {\left\| u - x \right\|}^{2} \right\} $$

For $ g \left( x \right) = {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} $ in the $ {\mathbb{R}}^{n} $ the is given by:

$$ \operatorname{Prox}_{\lambda {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{1}} = \begin{cases}
{x}_{i} - \lambda & \text{ if } {x}_{i} \geq \lambda \\ 
0 & \text{ if } \left| {x}_{i} \right| \leq \lambda \\ 
{x}_{i} + \lambda & \text{ if } {x}_{i} \leq -\lambda \\ 
\end{cases} $$

My question is, what would be the result if the domain is $ {\mathbb{C}}^{n} $?

Namely:

$$ \operatorname{Prox}_{\lambda {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{1}} \left( x \right) = \arg \min_{u} \left\{ {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} + \frac{1}{2 \lambda} {\left\| u - x \right\|}^{2} \right\}, \; u ,x \in {\mathbb{C}}^{n} $$

Thank You.

Comment: If you were to _guess_ what it is---seriously, just think about it visually, and take a wild guess---what would you say? I'll bet you get it right.

Comment: Another hint: try to write a formula for the real-valued prox function that doesn't require three separate cases. How would you do that?

Comment: @MichaelGrant, My bet is that the angle will be the same and the magnitude will "Shrinked" (Soft Threshold).

Comment: That is exactly right.

Comment: The issue is how to derive it form the definition. Yet it would require knowing the Sub Gradient of $ {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} $ on the Complex Domain. Which means, is it still the Complex Sign Function? How can I prove that?

Comment: Note that the problem is separable, so you need only consider $|u|+{1 \over 2 \lambda}  |x-u|^2$ for $x,u \in \mathbb{C}$. The subdifferential approach is probably overkill here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi(u,x) = \|u\|_1 + {1 \over 2\lambda} \|x-u\|_2^2$. With a slight abuse
of notation, note that 
$\phi(u,x) = \sum_k \phi(u_k,x_k)$, so we may as well assume that $u,x \in \mathbb{C}$.

If $x=0$, we see that $\operatorname{prox}_{\lambda {|\cdot|}} (x) = 0$, so assume $x \neq 0$.

Note that if $|\theta|=1$, then $\phi(u,x) = \phi(\theta u, \theta x)$ and
also $\phi(u,x) \ge \phi(\operatorname{re} u, \operatorname{re} x)$.

In particular, 
$\phi(u,x) = \phi({\bar{x} \over |x|} u, |x|) \ge \phi(\operatorname{re}({\bar{x} \over |x|} u), |x|)$, from which we see that (i) we need only
optimise over real $u$ and (ii)
$\operatorname{prox}_{\lambda {|\cdot|}} (x) = {|x| \over \bar{x}} \operatorname{prox}_{\lambda {|\cdot|}} (|x|)$, where the latter is
computed over a real domain (we have
$\operatorname{prox}_{\lambda {|\cdot|}} (|x|) = \max(0,|x|-\lambda)$).

**Notes**:

(i) ${|x| \over \bar{x}} = { x \over |x| }$.

(ii) The real (one or higher dimension) problem
$\min_u \|u\|_1 + {1 \over 2 \lambda } \|x-u\|_2^2$ has a nice solution
via a minor extension of the von Neumann mimimax [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem).
We have $\|u\|_1 =\max_{\|h\|_\infty \le 1} \langle h, u \rangle$ and
the problem can be written as
$\min_u \max_{\|h\|_\infty \le 1} \langle h, u \rangle + {1 \over 2 \lambda } \|x-u\|_2^2$. Applying the aforementioned theorem (with a minor extension to
deal with the non compact domain for $u$) we have
$\min_u \max_{\|h\|_\infty \le 1} \langle h, u \rangle + {1 \over 2 \lambda } \|x-u\|^2 = \max_{\|h\|_\infty \le 1} \min_u  \langle h, u \rangle + {1 \over 2 \lambda } \|x-u\|_2^2$ and solving the inner quadratic problem
gives
$\min_u \max_{\|h\|_\infty \le 1} \langle h, u \rangle + {1 \over 2 \lambda } \|x-u\|_2^2 = \max_{\|h\|_\infty \le 1} \langle h, x \rangle - {\lambda \over 2} \|h\|_2^2$ (with $\lambda h - (x-u) = 0$).

This is separable, and reduces to solving
$\max_{|h_k| \le 1} h_k x_k  - {\lambda \over 2} h_k^2$, which
has solution $h_k = \operatorname{sgn} x_k \min(1,{|x_k| \over \lambda})$, and
substituting into $u_k= x_k-\lambda h_k$ 
gives the solution $u_k=\operatorname{sgn} x_k \max(0,|x_k|-\lambda)$

Comment: Shouldn't it be, the solution I got (Only by Geometry) to the least, $ \frac{x}{\left| x \right|} \max \left( 0, \left| x \right| - \lambda \right) $? I +1 your answer. Thank You.

Comment: @Royi: Let me check, I could easily have made a mistake.

Comment: @Royi: If $x \neq 0$ we have ${x \over |x|} = {|x| \over \overline{x}}$.

Comment: @Royi: All the above are the same ${x \over |x|} = {|x| \over \overline{x}} = \overline{({|x| \over x})}$. Use whatever formula you are comfortable with, they are all equivalent.

Comment: Do we agree that $ \frac{x}{\left| x \right|} $ is a complex number with its magnitude equals to 1 (On the Unit Circle)? Also do we agree that $ \frac{x}{\left| x \right|} = {\left( \frac{\left| x \right|}{x} \right)}^{-1} $?

Comment: @Royi: I'm not sure what the point of this discussion is. Of course ${x \over |x|}$ is on the unit circle and $z = ({1 \over z})^{-1}$. I am not disagreeing with anything, just pointing out equivalences.

Comment: If we do, lets define $ z = t + w i $ on the unit circle, namely $ {t}^{2} + {w}^{2} = 1 $. Now, you say $ z = {z}^{-1} $. Let's see $ \frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{t + w i} = \frac{t - w i}{\left(t - w i\right) \left(t + w i\right)} = \frac{t - w i}{{t}^{2} + {w}^{2}} = t - w i = {z}^{*} \neq z $. Unless I missed something on your definition for $ x $ I don't think for complex numbers on the Unit Circle your statement holds.

Comment: @Royi: Can you tell me what statement you are referring to please? I never stated that $z =z^{-1}$?????

Comment: My Mistake, I missed you conjugation :-). I saw you were writing $ \frac{x}{\left| x \right|} = \frac{\left| x \right|}{x} $ which is false, while you were writing $ \frac{x}{\left| x \right|} = \frac{\left| x \right|}{\bar{x}} $ which is true. I missed that $ \bar{\cdot} $ (Conjugation) you added. My mistake for missing it, Sorry.