# Nuclear norm minimization of convolution matrix (circular matrix) with fast Fourier transform

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, machine-learning

I am reading a paper [Recovery of Future Data via Convolution Nuclear Norm Minimization](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIT.2022.3196707). Here, I know there is a definition for convolution matrix.

Given any vector $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)^\top\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with a certain kernel size $\tau\in\mathbb{N}^+$ ($1<\tau<n$), then its convolution matrix is given by
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{C}_{\tau}(\boldsymbol{x})=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_n & x_{n-1} & \cdots & x_{n-\tau+2} \\ x_2 & x_1 & x_n & \cdots & x_{n-\tau+3}  \\ x_3 & x_2 & x_1 & \cdots & x_{n-\tau+4} \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ x_n & x_{n-1} & x_{n-2} & \cdots & x_{n-\tau+1} \\
\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times\tau},
\end{equation}
which is also a circular matrix, but it is not a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) of size $n\times n$. In the case of circulant matrix, we can [utilize fast Fourier transform to solve the nuclear norm minimization problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4562565/738418).

In fact, I am interested in the nuclear norm minimization of the convolution matrix, just like
\begin{equation}
\min_{\boldsymbol{x}}~\|\mathcal{C}_{\tau}(\boldsymbol{x})\|_{*}+\frac{\lambda}{2}\|\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{z}\|_{2}^{2}
\end{equation}
where $\|\mathcal{C}_{\tau}(\boldsymbol{x})\|_{*}$ is the nuclear norm of $\mathcal{C}_{\tau}(\boldsymbol{x})$, i.e., the sum of singular values. $\boldsymbol{z}$ is a known variable.

**[Q]** Is it possible to utilize the fast Fourier transform to solve the nuclear norm minimization of the convolution matrix?